# How to use a Postman Mock Server from IntelliJ

Tags: api, intellij-idea, mocking, postman

I have a mock server running in Postman and I can access it with GET commands etc.

I can also view the GET commands from my web browser, for example

```
http://5cff3352-bd89-44c2-90b9-23b980d75f30.mock.pstmn.io//users/username/organisation
```

This all works fine, my problem is when I trying and access the mock server from IntelliJ. The process times out as shown below.

Any ideas please, thanks in advance.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:101)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
at org.apache.http.client.HttpClient$execute$0.call(Unknown Source)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder.doRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:2054)
at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.post(HTTPBuilder.java:349)
at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder$post$2.call(Unknown Source)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1180)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:821)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
at io.restassured.internal.filter.SendRequestFilter.filter(SendRequestFilter.groovy:30)
at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter$0.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
at io.restassured.filter.time.TimingFilter.filter(TimingFilter.java:56)
at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
at io.restassured.filter.log.StatusCodeBasedLoggingFilter.filter(StatusCodeBasedLoggingFilter.java:93)
at io.restassured.filter.log.ResponseLoggingFilter.filter(ResponseLoggingFilter.java:31)
at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
at io.restassured.filter.log.RequestLoggingFilter.filter(RequestLoggingFilter.java:122)
at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter$0.call(Unknown Source)
at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
at io.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1654)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:821)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:184)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1660)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:821)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:184)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:175)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:821)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:168)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:259)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at uk.co.kevsbox.automation.core.factory.CreateRequestFactory.postRequest(CreateRequestFactory.java:25)
at uk.co.kevsbox.automation.restassured_userservice.specs.PatchUserDetailsRequestSpec.callApiRequest(PatchUserDetailsRequestSpec.java:48)
at uk.co.kevsbox.automation.restassured_userservice.steps.UpdateUserDetailsSteps.patchUserDetails(UpdateUserDetailsSteps.java:51)
at uk.co.kevsbox.automation.restassured_userservice.steps.UpdateUserDetailsSteps.iMakePatchRequestToUsersEndpoint(UpdateUserDetailsSteps.java:40)
at ✽.When I make patch request to users endpoint with relationships(C:/Dev/RestAssured/restassured_userservice/src/test/resources/features/CreatePatchForOrganisation.feature:9)
```

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55142', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a proxy setting and a silly typo. All sorted now.